# How should destroyed Objects be handled?

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I'm developing a PIXI.js app and to cleanup resources in order to prevent memory leaks i'm using `DisplayObject.destroy`.

When a display object is destroyed a lot of its internal values get set to `null` and `_destroyed` gets set to true.

This is proving problematic as some of the application is event based rather than game loop based. Some of this logic tries to mutate display objects and errors out due to the lack of transform.

I'd be able to get away with this if items of a display object such as position and scale were not getters that are unguarded.

```
get x() {
  // Unguarded will error out if this.position is null!
  return this.position.x;
}
```

Right now as im in a Typescript environment i'm extending the display object and overwriting x,y etc with:

```
get x() {
  // As this.position is also a getter we have to go to transform to be safe
  return this.transform && this.position.x;
}
```

How should this be handled?
Why is `DisplayObject._destroyed` private?

Comment: Typically one would want to unsubscribe event listeners that are no longer valid.  Your event listeners should not have references to destroyed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Pace is right on that comment regarding event listeners. To me it sound like there could already be a memory leak with that logic. Since you are keeping references to objects, that have been destroyed with PIXIs .destroy method. So even when you destroy them from PIXI (e.g. from GPU), you are still keeping the objects in CPU / javascripts memory.

If you still really want to go that way, I would rather suggest you make own functionality and not overwrite PIXIs own functions. Since when PIXI gets an update on getters, you might end up with nasty bugs as you have overwritten the getter. So making just something like:

```
destroyObject(displayObject) {
    displayObject.destroy();
    displayObject.customDestroyed = true;
}
```

Comment: destroy will remove event emitters, the problem here isn't strictly event listeners.

Take an array of display objects that's stored somewhere. On an event(that isn't part of the game loop) iterate over those objects and move each object to the left.

There's no way to tell that an object within this array has been destroyed. I guess the only way to do this is to handle explicitly all locations where the object may be stored when it is destroyed and update them. Or create an event on the display object that is emitted when it is destroyed.